# NSSortDescriptor won't sort my dictionaries by a key

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using an UIActionSheet to sort the 100 dictionaries in my array by one of the keys. Some of the keys are NSStrings and others are NSNumbers.This code does the job:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Price" ascending:YES];
    }
if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES];
}
if (buttonIndex == 2) {
    sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Country" ascending:YES];
}
if (buttonIndex == 3) {
    sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Price" ascending:YES];
}
if (buttonIndex == 4) {
    sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Freshness" ascending:YES];
}
[objArr sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];
[[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

But on the last one (Freshness) it crashes with this error: `[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dd838e0`
The Freshness value of each dictionary is simply a number from 1-10. Can someone tell me what could be causing this and how to make it work? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That *should* work without creating your own custom comparator... How are the dictionaries getting created?  I bet what's happening is SOME of your `Freshness` values are `NSStrings` and some are `NSNumbers`, and they're getting compared with each other by accident.

When you load these out of the database or whatever, test them before you put them in their dictionaries with a `respondsToSelector:@selector(isEqualToNumber:)` and coerce any value `ids` that don't make the cut.

Comment: Thanks, one of the Freshness values was a string! :)

Comment: I was getting a similar error. One of the objects in the objArr was missing the key that it was sorting on. It would be the equivalent of not having a Freshness key/value pair in one of the objects. The error is the same though. Something to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
sortedArrayUsingFunction:context
```

Answer (score 0):

For the last one, try this:

```
sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Freshness" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue])
        {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue])
        {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        }
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }];
```